# How to pass parameters from %prep to %build?

Tags: rpm

I have the following problem: In the `%prep`, I run a command that returns a
value. I want to be able to use this value in the `%build`.

I was not able to do it with macros, because `%global` gets its value on init,
and `%declare` is executed when called. I also wasn't able to use bash parameters because they are not shared between
`%prep` and `%build`.

I have 2 workarounds: Do all in `%prep`, or save the value to a file. I'm not
comfortable with any of these workarounds.

This seems to be a simple task. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why can't `%prep` finish the prep?

Comment: It does. But I need a value from the %prep in the %build.

Comment: Then why isn't the value being generated in `%build`?

Comment: Because logically the process that creates this value belongs to the %prep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible. I found this Q&A on Stackoverflow titled: [Reassing values to %define variables in spec file - RPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519844/reassing-values-to-define-variables-in-spec-file-rpm), which stated this fact in several ways.

In searching I found only the method you mentioned of writing data to temporary files, using `mktemp` for example.